PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens Drupal 7 menu
Updating a working Drupal 7.99 site to Drupal 7.101
Mostly working except for menus. I can't edit existing menus nor add a new menu without getting this error.
PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens
The menu works but is not formatted properly.
Any ideas?
